# Can I pair a Bluetooth keyboard with my MacBook without logging in?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, keyboard

A portion of the keyboard on my MacBook Pro stopped working recently, and I'm not able to log in. However, I do have an Apple Bluetooth keyboard, it just isn't paired with my laptop. Is it possible to pair the keyboard without logging in?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible.

What you can do instead is to connect the Apple keyboard using a cable to the computer. That should allow you to log in.